# Regexp and accent

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a word censor.
I have this text :

```
$str = "Je connais ce con de conémi".
```

I want to replace "con" if it's a whole word, not in a another one.

If I do this :

```
preg_replace("/\b(con)\b/i", "###", $str);
```

the result is :

```
"Je connais ce ### de ###émi".
```

Conémi has been censored.
This is because of the "é" of conémi.

Comment: Please tag the language you use. PHP I guess?

Comment: @halfelf was it `preg_replace` that tipped you off? Lol

Comment: This seems to be a problem with PHP. JavaScript and Python both return `"Je connais ce ### de conémi"`.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for the lack of PHP flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `u` regex modifier

```
preg_replace("/\b(con)\b/iu", "###", $str)
                          ^--- here it is
```

or alternative solution is to use PCRE unicode characters:

```
preg_replace("/(?<=\p{Z}|\p{P}|^)con(?=\p{Z}|\p{P}|$)/i", "###", $str);
```

http://ideone.com/cCoiNp

Comment: All right. It works with the PCRE unicode characters. Thank you. Note : The "u" modifier doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Pax Maximinus: it fixes here, php 5.3.17